# Find Next in texteditor

Tags: java, swing, search

I am trying to code the search functionality in `JTextArea`.  I did it for find, but find next is where i am stuck.  The `JOptionPane` should not get closed until all the words are found in the `JTextArea`.

```
private void findActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    findString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Find What", "Find", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    text = editorTextArea.getText();
    index = text.indexOf(findString, 0);
    editorTextArea.setCaretPosition(index);
    editorTextArea.setSelectionStart(index);
    editorTextArea.setSelectionEnd(index + findString.length());
}
```

Comment: for better help sooner please edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) ,

Comment: "*The `JOptionPane` should not get closed until all the words are found in the `JTextArea`."*  The search does not ***begin*** until the option pane is closed, so I cannot see this requirement as being practical.

Answer (score 1):

Use non-modal JDialog and dispose it manually when you are done with the last find. For more details on JDialog check at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Comment: I think you mean "non-modal"?